# All buttons generate same event, generate same output

Tags: java, event-handling

I've written a code that generates a simple rectangle in the frame and changes the color of an already existing circle on the frame.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

class DrawRect extends JPanel{
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
          Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

         g2.draw(new Rectangle(200,200,200,200));
    }
}

class FillOval extends JPanel{
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
           Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

           int red = (int)(Math.random()*255);
           int green = (int)(Math.random()*255);
           int blue  = (int)(Math.random()*255);
           Color startColor = new Color(red,green,blue);

           red = (int)(Math.random()*255);
           green = (int)(Math.random()*255);
           blue = (int)(Math.random()*255);

          Color endColor = new Color(red,green , blue);
          GradientPaint gradient  = new GradientPaint(70,70,startColor,150,150,endColor);
          g2.setPaint(gradient);
          g2.fillOval(70,70,100,100);
    }
}

class MainGui {

     public static void main(String[] args){
             MainGui gui = new MainGui();
             gui.go();
    }
JFrame frame;
FillOval ov = new FillOval();
void go(){

  frame = new JFrame();
  JButton colorButton = new JButton("change color");
  JButton rectButton = new JButton("draw rectangle");

  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  colorButton.addActionListener(new colorListener());
  rectButton.addActionListener(new rectListener());

  frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, colorButton);
  frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, rectButton);
  frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, ov);

  frame.setSize(500,500);
  frame.setVisible(true);
 }

 class colorListener implements ActionListener{
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
            frame.repaint();
   }
}

 class rectListener implements ActionListener{
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
           DrawRect rect = new DrawRect();
           frame.add(rect);
           frame.revalidate();
           frame.repaint();
       }
}
}
```

Now, the problem is that `rectButton` button is changing the color of the circle in the frame along with generating a rectangle in the frame.

It has nothing to do with the event of `colorButton` button. Why is it behaving in such a way? And how should I fix it?

Comment: You're asking to repaint the frame. Every time the frame is being repainted, your paintComponent method is called (that's what its for). Every time it's called, it chooses a random color and paints the circle. Again (sinc eyou already asked that question), choosing a new color must be done in the color listener. Not in paintComponent().

Comment: So, it doesn't matter what event is generated for what button, `paintComponent` will always be called as long as graphics is involved.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `repaint` triggers the call of `paintComponent` where the color will always be chosen randomly. You will need to define `endColor` as a member of a `class`, initialized with `null`. In your `paintComponent` method check it against `null` and if it is `null`, initialize it. You will need to initialize it at `colorListener` as well. And in `paintComponent`, use the `endColor` member. This way you will not redefine `endColor` whenever `paintComponent` is called. Since you need to initialize `endColor` at multiple places, it is a good idea to implement a method for it and call that method whenever the color needs to be initialized to avoid code duplication.